# I want to assert the row text but getting AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'row'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

am trying to assert the row text in webtable but am facing issue,getting some attribute error.help me in this

```
    webtable=driver.find_element_by_class_name("dojoxGridScrollbox")        
    for row in webtable.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='dojox_grid__TreeView_1']/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr"):
        print(row.text)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    #assert webtable.row.text== name
    assert driver.row.find(name)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\rajesn\eclipse\Pyhton\GUI_Automation\GuiAutomationTest.py", line 11, in 
>       obj.peer_node()
>    File "C:\Users\rajesn\eclipse\Pyhton\GUI_Automation\gui_Module.py", line 83, in peer_node
>       assert driver.row.find(name)
>   AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'row'

Comment: Are you looking to test that `name` is included in any of the table rows or just in the __nth__ row in table body?

Comment: i want to assert the perticular row text which i will insert in webtable

Comment: That is not clear to me. Is row text inserted in a previous step? Does the insertion happen at the end of the table or does the row text go to the table top when row text is inserted?

Comment: row will get inserted at the top  ,I declared the name like this         name="APeerNode_0"+str(random.randint(1,10000))
and next i inspected the webelement and row by using class name and xpath.now i want to assert the row text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `xpath` is very expressive and can be for specific for selecting nodes in a tree, a loop isn't necessary for getting at the inserted table row.

If table row is inserted in top, you can write the query as

```py
first_tr_xpath = "(//*[@id='dojox_grid__TreeView_1']/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr)[1]"
first_tr, = webtable.find_elements_by_xpath(first_tr_xpath)
assert first_tr.text.find(name) != -1
```

If table row is inserted on end of table, it's more like

```py
last_tr_xpath = "(//*[@id='dojox_grid__TreeView_1']/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr)[last()]"
last_tr, = webtable.find_elements_by_xpath(last_tr_xpath)
assert last_tr.text.find(name) != -1
```

Comment: thank you so much @Oluwafemi Sule, It worked.i didn't understand y there is -1

Comment: `str.find(text)` returns `-1` when `text` isn't found in `str`, otherwise it returns the starting index position of `text` in `str`.

Comment: why not `assert name in last_tr.text`?